# Extracting characters from window and Linux

Tags: c++

Basically, window text editor puts "\r" ,"\n" at the end. So when i have a word "compile" in window's file, it is actually "compile\n\r",

when i extract characters by using

```
char letter; 
fin.get(Letter);
```

from the file and put my linked list taking char character

```
list<char> myList;
```

I would get {'c', 'o', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'i', 'e', '\r', '\n'} in my list.

Then when I call

```
itr = myList.end();
```

it will give the iterator containing value '\n', is that right?? So if i want to access to the 'e', I have to do "--itr" twice. Is that right??

Then when it is Linux, I would have  {'c', 'o', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'i', 'e', '\n'}, and calling "itr = myList.end()" will give me the iterator containing the value '\n', So I have to do "--iterator" to get to character 'e'. Is my understanding correct?

Basically, I am using notepad for my text file and when i have a word "compile" with  no space and when i calling "itr = myList.end()" It gives me the iterator containing some space and i don't know what it is. Then when I do "--itr" then It gives me the iterator containing the last letter while I am expecting to have the last letter iterator when i do "--itr" twice becuase it is window's text file.

Could anyone explain what is going on??

Comment: I think you need to double check the documentation on what [`std::list::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/end) returns.

Comment: A single installation of Microsoft Windows is still called "Windows", not "Window" – it's a proper name, not a plural.

Comment: As an off-topic aside, once you've anyway learnt how to use `std::list`, you might also consider just using `dos2unix` to convert your line endings rather than handle this in code.

Comment: when reading text files, use `getline` instead and forget about different line endings

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as NathanOliver pointed out, **`std::list::end` returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the container**.

In your case, with Windows CRLF end of lines, `auto it = myList.end(); it--` will have `it` containing LF (0x0A). In the case of Linux LF end of lines, it will also contain LF.

A second `it--` will have it point to 0x0D in the case of a Windows CRLF file, or the `e` from `compile` you are looking for in your example.

So you can use a simple conditional on a second `--it` to check if it is 0x0D. If it is, you know the file is a Windows format and will need to decrement iterator once more to get to the last character.

To illustrate this, look at the following code. It's very limited: no error checking, no bounds checkings, etc..

**Please note that there are much better ways to handle opening / handling a file with unknown line endings than the sample code below**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char buffer;

  list<char> l;
  ifstream f;
//  f.open("crlf.txt");
  f.open("lf.txt");

  while (f.get(buffer).good())
    l.push_back(buffer);

  auto it = l.end();
  it--;

  if (*it == 0x0A) // if true it's LF or CRLF file
  {
    --it;
    if (*it == 0x0D) // if true it's CRLF
    {
      cout << "File is CRLF / Windows" << endl;
      --it; // get to the char before the newline
    }
    else
      cout << "File is LF / Linux" << endl;
  }

  // 'it' here always refers to the last character
  cout << "'it' points to " << *it << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

To test the code below I did the following:

```
echo "compile" > lf.txt
cp lf.txt crlf.txt
unix2dos crlf.txt
```